# Angular 2 - same timer across all users

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I created a timer which has to work exactly the same to all users **in the same time**.

I saved in my database the `start_time` (timestamp when the timer starts)
and wrote the following expression to calculate how much time left:

```
this.timeCheckSub = Observable.interval(1000)
.subscribe(() => {
  this.timer = this.TURN_TIME - (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - this.room.start_time);
});
```

`this.TURN_TIME` - Number in seconds (set to 15)

`this.timer` shows 15.. 14..13.. and in some devices: 17..16..14.. etc

The problem is that each device shows `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000` as different time based on his computer clock.

How I can work it out in order to show the same timer across all devices?

I know I can just count the number of seconds left using the observable, but it will not work as excepted when the user refresh the page, or when the user has some delay loading.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Date.now` is the time in MS elapsed since 01.01.1970 UTC and should be the same on each device! The only reason it might not be the same is the case, that a user manually alters the clock/time on the device (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: @olsn Interesting.. trying to figure out why from my mobile device the timer starts from 16 while in my computer it starts from 15.

Comment: Maybe it depends an when the timer is started, e.g. you divide by 1000 and then floor it - this means that a difference of just 1ms could cause a displayed difference of 1s since `Math.floor(999 / 1000) => 0` ..+1ms `Math.floor(1000 / 1000) => 1` - secondly you `interval` is set to 1000ms, this means that the _real_ time could also differ from the _displayed_ time by (worst case) 999.9ms

Comment: Well it's actually 2-3 seconds different, all users show the same screen in the same time (may be max of ~0.4sec different). I save the timer start time in my database, and it's `this.room.start_time` in my code. the start_time is same for all users.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know you can work around Date.now() that will be different is to send the timestamp from the server. But this will not be exactly precise of course, since it takes time to reach the client. I don't think it is really possible to guarantee the same time by doing calculations on the client where you don't control the environment.

How accurate the timer should be for your needs? Perhaps there is some other way you can solve it? E.g. run the timer on a server and check every now and then from client side or use server push updates.

Comment: All users have to answer the same question within a time limit, in the same time

Comment: What you can do is to send the remaining time from server and begin countdown. There will be some differences based on the response time, but not much. E.g. if you query the server and it says 25 minutes left, then you can use the timer with this value independent of the client clock. You will still have to rely on the clock for the difference, but that is less likely to fail (though user can change the clock on the fly and "prolong" the time left). Best way is to have a control on the server when the submission occurs as well.